# P2P connection in WAN using java

Tags: java, serversocket

I want to make P2P connection using java. It works fine for LAN but it is showing Connection Timed Out for WAN.So can somebody tell me how can I achieve this.

Comment: Can you share your code and the error trace?

Comment: I am just using ServerSocket for the server and Socket for client and i am using the public ip of the server